# Cruise Control .Net Modifying Dashboard

Tags: cruisecontrol.net

i would like to modify the CCNET dashboard, so it shows me the projects buildTime, when i enter the "ServerReport". Like the startTime, it should also display the buildTime. Is it possible to modify the dashboard like that? Until now, i did not find anything...

Answer (score 1):

the WebDashboard is using an MVC pattern and templates.

You'll find the templates [here](https://github.com/ccnet/CruiseControl.NET/tree/master/project/WebDashboard/templates).

Make your adjustments there and check if the controller is passing the correct data to its view. The standard action are in the WebDashboard/plugins/ folder.

Finally run the build-all.bat in the project root to create a new deployment.

Answer (score 0):

In your WebDashboard\templates folder look for the file ProjectParameters.vm and you can change the following html tag:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ForceBuild" value="Force" />
```

From there change it to the following:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ForceBuild" value="MyValue" />
```